# Using Django sessions to set a user-like field on a model

Tags: python, django, session, django-sessions

I'm writing an small app to demonstrate auctions to a group of students.  I want each student to be able to place bids on a few (more than 1, fewer than 10) items and then show them the distribution of the bids on each item.  I want to make sure each person only places a single bid on each item.  (These are teenagers, and I'm sure someone will be tempted to cause trouble by trying to submit 10 different bids on each item.)

I want each user to be able to see the current value of their bid on any item they've bid on.  And I'd like to let them revise their bids (for a certain period of time).  To do this, I'll need some way to tag a bid to an individual user (so they can only see/edit their own bids).  The models look something like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Lot(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    openforbids = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name

class Bid(models.Model):
    lot = models.ForeignKey('Lot')
    amount = models.FloatField()
    bidderid = **something goes here**

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Bid on lot %d' % self.lot
```

So the question is, what form should the `bidderid` field take in the `Bid` model?

- I could do a full blown `User` model and require each student to sign up at the beginning of the lecture.  Then make the `bidderid` a `ForeignKey` into `User`.  That seems a bit much.  I'd rather not implement the signup pages or force them to use passwords.
- I could make the `bidderid` a `CharField` and let each student type something in.  But that doesn't provide any link between the bids each person places across a variety of items.  I would put a `unique_together` constraint on the `(lot, bidderid)` tuple, but that wouldn't prevent a student from simply placing many bids by making up a new `bidderid` string several times.
- I could make the `bidderid` a `CharField` but then automatically fill it with information from the `request.session`.

I'd like to go the third route and use `sessions` to automatically give me a unique id for each person using the app.  I've tried reading up on `sessions` in Django, but haven't gotten a good understanding of how I'd do this.  I'd like to just implement a custom `save` method for the `Bid` model that will set the `bidderid` to be some unique thing from the `session`.  How would I do this?  What is the name of the unique session identifier that I should use?  In general, how do you implement things like this so that they don't blow chunks when you attempt to create model instances from the console.  I.e. if I implement a `save` method that sets `self.bidderid = something.from.request.session` then what will happen when I try to save a `bid` instance from the console where there is no `request` object?

Similarly, if I want to let the students associate their names with bids, what would be a good way to do this in the above session-driven framework?  Ideally when they went to the main page, they'd see a single form field that asks "What's your name".  When they submitted it, I would store a line in a `SessionName` model which would have two fields:

```
class SessionName(models.Model):
   sessionid = **the unique thing from request.session that we use to ID users**
   chosenname = models.CharField() # the value they submit in the form
```

Then throughout the app, we can associate bids made from a session with the `chosenname` they input at the start of the lecture.  Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to pregenerate as many user accounts as you need for the students and hand out username / password at the beginning of the lecture. Teenagers are familiar with this nowadays so no need to make things more complex for yourself than necessary. Implement functionality to let a user fill in their name after logging in and store that name. You can then allow the students to place bids and to display their name along with it.

This approach associates the bids with a user account and prevents messy things with stale sessions and so on. After the lecture you can keep the data or delete it and start fresh for the next lecture. It also means you can enforce constraints such as less than 10 bids and being able to edit the bids for a limited amount of time (e.g., store the time when the bid was placed in your database).

Comment: Really don't want to go the "make a real login for each user" route.  It will slow things down and some students will probably not bother trying the site with any speed bumps in the way.  Can you suggest the best way to proceed with the `sessions` route?